# Include JsonIgnore for Virtual Tables during Scaffold-DbContext?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate my DB Context/Models in .NET Core.

It's generating the models without issue, however what I'd like to do is include the Json.NET attribute `[JsonIgnore]` on any virtual property it generates. This way if I serialize an object it won't automatically include and convert the table relationships.

Is something like this possible? I can manually add the attribute after the fact, but then I'm not getting the benefit of pure generation.

Comment: If you try to directly return models from your controller, you may consider avoiding it. Its pretty bad practice and persistence leaks in other layers of your application and every part your database model changes it breaks your API, so its very fragile

Comment: I do understand those concerns, thanks. In this situation I'm fine with just returning the models. Less code overhead to translate the models into DTOs as its a simple API. Just wondering if my original question is possible.